# Favicon при отправки email со своего сайта

Tags: email, html, php

Как сделать, чтобы при отправке сообщения со своего сайта, у пользователя возле адреса отправителя была favicon сайта с которого отправлено сообщение?
Пробовал указывать в <head> у письма адрес до favicon.iso, но почтовики игнорируют тег <head>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понимаете ли, что просто так иконку не добавить, нужно что бы ваш сайт был соц. сетью или чем нибудь капец-пипец популярным.

Comment: понятно, спасибо